# best way to generate seed in java

Tags: java, web-services, encryption, encoding

Which is the best way to generate a random token/seed? Any latest java library to do it?
Is method 1 more random or method 2 ? Which is better of these two?

```
//Method 1:

private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
public static String generaterandomtoken()
{
    String str=new BigInteger(100, random).toString(32);
    return str;
}

//Method 2: 

private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
public static String generaterandomtoken()
{
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    long millis=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    random.setSeed(millis);
    String ran=new BigInteger(100, random).toString(32);
    return ran;
}
```

Comment: Your second method is much better that your first, but you need to define your requirements. By passing the `millis`, you will get the best distribution of "random" results. For testing, you may want reproducible results, however.

Comment: Note that SecureRandom is not guaranteed to produce the same random sequence for the same seed every time.

Answer (score 0):

The `random`function uses time as its input in both examples.

I believe both Methods are equally random, however method 1 is easier to read and slightly more efficient